# Access the original label in cleveref's \crefformat

Tags: labels, cleveref

Can I access the original label in `cleveref`'s `\crefformat`? In this MWE, I am  trying to get the same output as in the first line, but with the second line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{section}{#2the \nameref*{#1} section#3}
\begin{document}

Please read the \nameref{sec:Introduction} section!

Please read \cref{sec:Introduction}!

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}

\end{document}
```

However, this is what I get:

```
line 9: Reference `1' on page 1 undefined
: There were undefined references.
```

This is of course not unexpected, since in `\crefformat`, `#1` is replaced by the section number `1`, as explained in the documentation. However, `#2` and `#3` are used for hyperlinking, and `#4` does not exist, so I wonder whether, and how, I can access the original label (in this case, `sec:Introduction`) within `\crefformat`.

I guess one workaround would be a macro that returns the the nth section label, given n, but that would become messy, I suppose.

Another idea that I had is to patch `cleveref`, maybe to the extent such that my MWE makes sense with `\section*` instead of `\section` - because as it is, `\cref{sec:Introduction}` does not output anything useful (not even `the` or `section`) when the section does not have a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to access the current label name directly, but it can be stored in `\cref@getref` (thereby changing the command slightly, say to define `\@lastusedlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\def\cref@getref#1#2{%
  \xdef\@lastusedlabel{#1}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#2\csname r@#1@cref\endcsname%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo#2}}%
\creflabelformat{section}{#2the \nameref*{\@lastusedlabel} section#3}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Please read the \nameref{sec:Introduction} section!

Please read \cref{sec:Introduction}!

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compressed your solution into `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter \apptocmd{\cref@getref}{\xdef\@lastusedlabel{#1}}{}{error} \crefformat{section}{#2the \nameref*{\@lastusedlabel} section#3} \makeatother` to make it future-proof, but that does not change the main idea. Thanks!

Comment: @bers: `future-proof` is relative. A patch may also become disfunctional if the underlying command changes etc.

Comment: Certainly true, it is not optimal either. But if future-proof is relative, then I find that my solution is "more" future-proof :)

Comment: @bers: And mine does not need an extra package ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found myself with a similar problem, and realised that the proposed patch is not sufficient for range-formats.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523218/cleveref-format-accessing-label) I made another question (I had no reputation points to comment here) seeking for a more complete approach.

Actually, it seems that I found a fully-working solution by myself.