# Which command do I need to \protect to make latexdiff work?

Tags: cleveref, latexdiff

I have used the answer from [Access the original label in cleveref's \crefformat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319410/) to access the label of a `cleveref` reference. This worked fine until I through `latexdiff` into the game. Now, my highly simplified diff result looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319410/
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\cref@getref}{\xdef\@lastusedlabel{#1}}{}{error}
\crefformat{section}{the #2``\nameref*{\@lastusedlabel}''#3 section}
\makeatother

% latexdiff preamble
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}}
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{\uwave{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \section{\DIFadd{Foo}}
    \label{foo}

    \DIFadd{\mbox{\cref{foo}}}
\end{document}
```

The error message is `! Dimension too large.
\UL@on ...UL@height \advance \UL@height -\ULdepth`

My guess is that I need to `\protect` one of the commands, but I can't really tell which one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect `\DIFadd` inside of `\section`. This is because `\section` writes its argument to the `.aux` file in order to allow support for things like a table of contents, but if you used any counters or local definitions in the argument to `\section`, you want those to be correctly defined when written into the table of contents. Thus, `\section` first recursively expands its argument before writing it to the `.aux` file. However, `\DIFadd` doesn't like to be recursively expanded. Saying `\section{\protect\DIFadd{foo}}` or defining `\DIFadd` using `\DeclareRobustCommand` will solve your problem.

Comment: Replacing `\section{\DIFadd{Foo}}` by `\section{\protect\DIFadd{Foo}}` does not change anything (I had tried that - forgot to mention it). Also, replacing `\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}}` by `\DeclareRobustCommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}}` (or the same with `\DIFaddtex`) does not help. Not even doing all three does anything, it seems.

Comment: Try removing `\DIFadd` around `\mbox{\cref{foo}}`.

Comment: Yes, that might work. But this is what `latexdiff` puts. It would be hard for me to find out when to remove `\DIFadd`, automatically.