# Cleveref format, accessing label

Tags: cleveref

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319410/access-the-original-label-in-cleverefs-crefformat) a solution is proposed to patch `cleveref` `\crefformat` in order to give access to the last used label.

Unfortunately, it seems that the patch is not sufficient to handle cases where multiple labels are given as argument to a single `\cref{}` command. In particular, range formats seem to be problematic.

How can I handle all cases?

Here is a MWE (well, minimal enough):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\xdef\@curr@label{?}
\apptocmd{\cref@getref}
    {%
        \xdef\@curr@label{#1}%
    }%
    {}{error}

\newrobustcmd{\mytag}{%
    \textsuperscript{%
        \ensuremath{\to}%
        \cpageref{\@curr@label} 
        (\@curr@label)%
    }%
}

\creflabelformat{section}{#2#1#3\mytag{\@curr@label}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:1}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 2}\label{sec:2}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 3}\label{sec:3}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 4}\label{sec:4}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 5}\label{sec:5}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 6}\label{sec:6}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 7}\label{sec:7}\ldots\clearpage

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Single cref: \cref{sec:1}
    \item Already-sorted range cref: \cref{sec:1,sec:2,sec:3,sec:4}
    \item To-be-sorted range cref: \cref{sec:3,sec:2,sec:1,sec:4}
    \item To-be-sorted multi-range cref: \cref{sec:5,sec:1,sec:3,sec:2,sec:7,sec:6}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This produces (I'm showing only the page with section "Test"):

[image: Excerpt from page 8]

It can be seen that the highlighted labels, as captured by the patched `\cref@getref`, are wrong, as they correspond to the labels of the last section in each range.

My current goal is to show pointers to the page of each `\cref`. However, I believe that having access to the all labels as long as they are processed by `\cref` (that is after sorting and compression) would be extraordinarily useful for many purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution. I post it here as a candidate answer, hoping to help others.

Clearly, the ideal approach would be to have a native access to each label given to `\cref` commands. I hope this feature will be added soon.

Anyway, by looking into the source code of the `cleveref` package, it seems that only the last two used labels are needed to handle all cases.

Hence, we can simply patch `\@cref@getref` to enable storing of the last two seen labels (in two distinct macros).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\xdef\@curr@label@prev@last{a?}
\xdef\@curr@label@last{b?}
\apptocmd{\cref@getref}
    {%
        \xdef\@curr@label@prev@last{\@curr@label@last}%
        \xdef\@curr@label@last{#1}%
    }%
    {}{error}


\newrobustcmd{\mytag}[1]{%
    \textsuperscript{%
        \ensuremath{\to}%
        \cpageref{#1} 
        (#1)%
    }%
}

\creflabelformat{section}{#2#1#3\mytag{\@curr@label@last}}%
\crefrangelabelformat{section}{%
    #3#1#4\mytag{\@curr@label@prev@last} 
    to~#5#2#6\mytag{\@curr@label@last}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:1}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 2}\label{sec:2}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 3}\label{sec:3}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 4}\label{sec:4}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 5}\label{sec:5}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 6}\label{sec:6}\ldots\clearpage
\section{Section 7}\label{sec:7}\ldots\clearpage

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Single cref: \cref{sec:1}
    \item Already-sorted range cref: \cref{sec:1,sec:2,sec:3,sec:4}
    \item To-be-sorted range cref: \cref{sec:3,sec:2,sec:1,sec:4}
    \item To-be-sorted multi-range cref: \cref{sec:5,sec:1,sec:3,sec:2,sec:7,sec:6}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which correctly produces:

[image: Excerpt from page 8]